# Accepting Input From Barcode Scanner Without Using Textbox

Tags: c++, textbox, keyboard, serial-port, barcode

I need to read a scanned barcode without implementing a textbox.
My understanding is that most barcode scanners are just emulating a keyboard and so the input will be indistinguishable. What would be a good way to read the 'keyboard' input without the use of a textbox? I'm using C++ with wxwidgets.

Comment: I have used a barcode scanner in one my apps, but the language was C#. what barcode scanner does writes the written barcode into an active textfield on the screen. what do you mean by " a good way to read the "keyboard" input without the use of a textbox? You mean when is no textbox and user is typing on the keyboard?

Comment: Get a serial bar code scanner and read the data direct from the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using barcode setup as OPOS device (not as a virtual keyboard).

OPOS has pretty good interface.

Comment: I've also come across this article.

My question isn't so much about how I would distinguish between the barcode scanner and the keyboard, but effectively: how can I accept text input (from the keyboard or barcode scanner) without needing a textbox?

I should have made this more clear.

Comment: I deleted the link, because it was a bit misleading.
By use of OPOS interface, you'll have two different ways of input - keyboard and barcode scanner.